# doctrine annotation constant concatenation

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, concatenation, constants

i'm trying to use class constant in a doctrine annotation, as explained here : http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#constants

for example, this works like a charm :

`@MappableProperty(description=Company::ACTIVITY_NATURE_BIC)`

But I don't want to parse a raw constant, I would like to concatenate it with a string.

what I would like to achieve is something like this :

`@MappableProperty(description="Activity nature, for example Company::ACTIVITY_NATURE_BIC")`

as expected, this doesn't work. Is constant concatenation impossible in doctrine annotation ?

**EDIT : after some research, this is impossible to parse both string and constants at the same time right now. might be implemented in the future.**

Answer (score 1):

One can't use constants concatenation in annotations, but one can concatenate strings and constants into another class constant and then use it in the annotation.

For instance:

```php
class Company {
    public const ACTIVITY_NATURE_BIC = "[...]";
    public const ACTIVITY_NATURE_DESCRIPTION = "Activity nature, for example ".self::ACTIVITY_NATURE_BIC;

    /** @MappableProperty(description=Company::ACTIVITY_NATURE_DESCRIPTION) */
    private $activityNature;
}
```